# Duplicate items in angular material drag and drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-8

is there some way in angular material to prevent duplicate items in drop list?
here is example code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjex4y-43l7uh

I try to check if the item already exists in an array with `event.currentIndex` but this is not correct, because, sometimes I get the wrong value.

```
event.container.data.included(event.container.data[event.currentIndex])
```

In stackblitz i need to use .indexOf() insead od .included(), because something not working

Comment: so wanna say if you drop some item it should not be copied if already exist right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check current item using `previousIndex`  and check if item already exist or not if exist then return like

```
 {
      let idx=event.container.data.indexOf(event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]);
      if(idx != -1){
        return;//if item exist
      }
      copyArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjex4y-uuwcde)

Comment: thnx very mush... and pls, do you know how to remove item from list?

Comment: no, from `DONE` list... becaouse, from DONE list i can not drag item to `ToDo´ list

Comment: can you explain it with some example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjex4y-yjveye?file=app/cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html   here, you can not move an element from `done` to `ToDo` list to remove it from `DONE` list...soo, you need to take element from `DONE` list and drop it outside to remove it from the list.

Comment: i am not sure about that but there is something called `exit` in [api doc](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDragDrop) but not sure about the use of it

Answer (score 0):

about your question to remove the element when drag outside you can use the "Output" `cdkDragDropped`. The event return an object of type `CdkDragDrop` that have a property `isPointerOverContainer`. When this property is false you drop the item "outside" the cdk-drop-list.

```
<div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag 
        (cdkDragDropped)="dropped($event)" >{{item}}</div>

  dropped(event:any){
    if (!event.isPointerOverContainer)
      event.previousContainer.data.splice(event.previousIndex,1)
  }
```

Well, a brief explanation about cdk-drop-list:

A cdk-drop-list it's only a "mechanic" to change in general two arrays (really you can "transport" any data). You can add/remove elements to one or to another one array, you can interchange elements in the arrays or whatever.

1. A cdk-drop-list has a "data": generally an array but can be any
   object
2. Inside the each cdk-drop-list we have one or more cdk-drag: elements
   that we can drag.
3. a cdk-droplist have events that we can "capture": e.g.
   cdkDropListDropped
4. a cdk-drag also have events that we can "capture": e.g.
   cdkDragDropped
5. In this events the argument (see the type) is an object with
   properties. A lot of this object have a property the cdk-drop-list
   from and to drag/drop : "container" and "previousContainer" (so we
   can get the "data" using "container.data" and
   "previousContainer.data) and the index. So we can get the element
   that is dragged previousContainer.data[previousIndex] and the
   position where is dropped.

You can do anything with this elements